# Mysql : can a primary key column with autoincrement be defined to start with zero?

Tags: mysql

I need to store a build number which will start with zero and autoincrement if nothing is provided.

One solution would be to make it only a primary key and not autoincrement. However,I want it to be primary key auto increment and start with zero. Is this possible?

Comment: You need a column in your table called: 'build_number' which you maintain any way you wish. It has **no** relation to table:id. Please do not try and relate the 'table:id' to this. It will end in tears.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html), you could try this:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 0;
```

If that doesn't work then I can't imagine what would.  Personally, though, I would maintain build numbers externally instead of using auto_increment, if only because auto_increment will re-use values if you remove the row(s) with the largest keys.

Comment: This auto increment doesn't work! It will always start with 1 even if you set it to 0. Looks like i have no option other than maintain it using another column.